# IE7 Elements shrink on hover

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7

I would post code along with this but I can't seem to find out what type of scenario it occurs in but in IE7, certain elements seem to shrink when you hover over them and as you hover, unhover and rehover them they keep shrinking and shrinking until they are very small blocks of colour. It seem to be elements where thy ahve dimensions like width: 50% and height: 100px. But not 100% sure on this.

Any idea what could be causing this? On first display or after a refresh the site is fine but hovering over has this effect.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Absolutely no way to tell what's happening here without _some_ code. And IE7 has almost no market share anymore, ignore it ;)

Comment: Agreed. Myself & my agency stopped supporting it since the turn of the year (0.57% share the last I checked). The longer we support it, the longer people keep using it.

Comment: sounds like a javascript mousein handler is messing with your elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using `boxsizing.htc`? Remove it (yep layout is broken but that's a test). Is the bug gone?

I don't have the solution except when removing the HTC from ONE element is sufficient but layout isn't affected. To remove it, just redeclare behavior property with `url()` value:

```
.ie67 .noboxsizing {
    behavior: url();
}
```

Comment: Yes, removing boxsizing.htc does fix the issue. Hmm. Really could do with IE7 support for this site. I'll have a look around. Thanks for your help tracking down the issue. It's very hard to do web searches for an issue when you are not sure of the cause.

Comment: Tracking down> I had this exact problem a while ago. Just reading "IE7" and "shrink" in your title was enough to remember about this bug ;) Try adding the HTC except for one key element yet to be found, but that's pretty hard. Note that I didn't read about the numerous issues https://github.com/Schepp/box-sizing-polyfill/issues about this HTC (it does numerous things, no dissent)

Comment: Still having real difficulty in being able to use the htc file but solve the areas that shrink. It's not happening on some areas of the site but this site in particular has two areas suffering badly from it. I have tried removing the behaviour from them but that makes no difference. It's soo annoying. This si the final issue I really need to fix.

Comment: Maybe try to avoid having a width on this element and set width on a container and your element as width: auto or better display: block? In other news, to hell with IE7. Their users must see far far worse on other sites nowadays...